# Maximum serialization depth exceeded (does the object being serialized have a circular reference?)

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to save this simple class, but MongoDB is not accepting.

```
public class CredentialSet
{
    public CredentialSet()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<CredentialSet>();
    }
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string WebSite { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int Owner { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<CredentialSet> Items { get; set; }

    public CredentialSet parent { get; set; }
}
```

***Maximum serialization depth exceeded (does the object being serialized have a circular reference?).***

How to solve it?

Comment: Do `FILHOS` or `parent` produce a circular reference to the same `CredentialSet` object?

Comment: object A reference object B and object B directly or indirectly reference object A again.

Comment: Guess you'll have to redesign it either to not have circular references or instead indirectly reference other `CredentialSets` (perhaps by `_id` instead?)

Comment: Without a clean solution to this issue, I will consider MongoDB a hype.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved problem in our core project on this way.

```
'
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using AutoMapper;

var stringContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_mapper.Map<DataDTO>(newdata), new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }).ToString();

 _mongoService.Save(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataDTO>(stringContent));


//mongo service save method
public async void Save(DataDTO dataDTO)
{
  await observationCollection.InsertOneAsync(dataDTO));
}        
'
```